# Failure to install .net 3.5 on Windows 10 Error 800f0922

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, .net-framework

I am unable to install .net 3.5 on my new install of windows 10. Steam tries to install this for basically every game I try to download, but it always fails with the error code of 800F0922.

I have attempted a number of different things

- running the command:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /Source:E:\sources\sxs /All /LimitAccess
```

where E: is a Win10 ISO (the same one I installed with)

- running an offline installer version of the update
- System Reserved is 33% full on 500mb partition
- Putting a reg key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing with the name LocalSourcePath and REG_SZ value of e:\sources\sxs
- Running the command

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:E:\sources\sxs\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab
```

- Running the command

```
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:NetFx3~~~~
```

- I have no gpos set
- restarting the windows update service (wuauserv)
- installing from appwiz.cpl > enable windows feature > .net 3.5
- ran this string of commands:

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old 
    #that failed as an admin cmd lacks permissions
ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 catroot2.old
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver

and then

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

Every different way of installing listed the exact same error 800f0922

- My DISM Log errors are here:

the entire log can be found at this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/FpubWd0m

```
2016-06-07 18:19:40, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6348 TID=10024  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x800f0922) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2016-06-07 18:19:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6348 TID=4832 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0922)
2016-06-07 18:19:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6348 TID=4832 Failed processing package changes - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChanges(hr:0x800f0922)
2016-06-07 18:19:40, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6348 TID=4832 Loaded servicing stack for online use only. - CDISMPackageManager::RefreshInstanceAndLock
2016-06-07 18:19:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6348 TID=4832 Failed while processing command add-package. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0922)
2016-06-07 18:19:40, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6348 TID=4832 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2016-06-07 18:19:40, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=800F0922
```

I am stumped, guys.

Comment: have you added a new MUI /language pack after installing ? In this case, you need to downlaod the ISO for the other MUI and copy the SxS folder of this MUI version + your original ISO to C:\SxS so that it includes both MUI files

Comment: I only have the single default of English (Cannot be removed)

Comment: I need the CBS log folder to see more. Also the microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab is part of the “Windows 10 Features on Demand” ISO, not the normal ISO, so this doesn't work. You need to get it via MSDN

Comment: copy the SxS folder from the mounted ISO to C: and make sure the SYSTEM, admin have full access to the folder. Now point to this folder in the DISM command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, evetually it was related to prior installation of .net 4.6 feature

These are the steps I used:

1. In the Programs and Features screen select from the left pane "Turn Windows features on or off"
2. At the beggining of the list there should be .Net Framework 3.5... and .Net Framework 4.6... nodes
3. The 4.6 option might be selected or partially selected, so verify what the selections are, remove them and click OK - they should be removed
4. Execute the DISM command from above which should succeed
5. Return to the features screen and apply back the options you removed

Hope it helps

Comment: Just tried this and it worked! Thanks a ton dude.

Answer (score -1):

After I updated to Windows 10 Anniversary Update (Build 1607), I could not install .NET Framework 3.5. I tried the answer by Assafl, but it did not work for me. What finally worked for me was to update to Windows 10 Creators Update (Build 1703). I was then able to easily install .NET Framework 3.5 by turning it on from the *Windows Features* dialog.